# Where does the [Authorize] attribute fetch login URL from in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity, authorize-attribute

When I use Authorize attribute on any of my actions, it redirects me to my login view. I don't remember saving a login url anywhere, I read that in .Net 4.x, login url was saved in .config. We don't have any web.config in .Net core, nor did I set it up in appSettings.json.

Where is Authorize attribute fetching the login URL from? Does it have anything to do with UseAuthentication() middleware? I am using using built-in authentication functionality using Identity.

Thank you.

Comment: If you choose individual authentication when you create a new project, it will automatically implement and identity, and for example in asp.net core, it will implement views and a controller which will be found on the solution explorer in the identity folder

Comment: Yes, as you methioned, the `Authorize` attribute in asp.net core identity is a packaged method. You can read this link to get a better understanding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I've this question also. I did not customize any part of Individual Accounts Login Scaffolding. [Authorize] attribute tends to send the user to /Account/Login whereas actual login page is under /Identity/Account/Login. Not sure where to configure this.

Comment: For Cookie Authentication, this is configurable in `ConfigureServices()` using CookieAuthenticationOptions: 
`services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                });`